# Why Coq does not infer the type parameter

Tags: coq

I've defined the following type which has the exact same structure as `option`.

```
Inductive optionX A := NoneX | SomeX (a : A).
```

While `Check Some 1` correctly infers the type parameter A, `Check SomeX 1` produces the message

```
The term "1" has type "nat" while it is expected to have type "Type".
```

Am I missing something? Note that it works fine if I explicitly provide the type parameter: `Check SomeX(nat) 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coq has an *implicit arguments* mechanism for this kind of situation:

```
Inductive optionX A := NoneX | SomeX (a : A).
Arguments NoneX {A}.
Arguments SomeX {A} a.  (* Curly braces means "please try to infer this" *)

Check SomeX 1.

(* You can turn off argument inference with @ *)
Check @NoneX nat. (* optionX nat *)
```

Note that the expression that you had earlier, `SomeX(nat) 1`, is parsed the same way as `SomeX nat 1`, which is the constant `SomeX` applied to the arguments `nat` and `1`.  The mechanism for supplying type arguments is the same as how you supply other kinds of arguments.

The [reference manual](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/extensions/implicit-arguments.html) has more information on implicit arguments.